# Oracle (ODBC) - excel connection

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I have to connect to database via excel. I am using ODCB plugin from Oracle. I know that xlsm file is correct because it works on my friend's computer. When I am tring to connect excel does not shows ane error window but it just shut down. What can be cause of that action. 
Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: Which Oracle Client is installed on the machine? Which ODBC driver do you use?

Comment: I have downloaded client from this page. 
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/database12c-win64-downloads.html
And the version is below:
Oracle Database Client (12.1.0.2.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)
ODBC driver was installed with that package.

Comment: Is your Excel 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: It's  32-bit Excel

Comment: Are you sure you selected the correct ODBC Oracle driver? (there are several different ones). Did you install more than just one Oracle Client? Check carefully the name of the driver. ODBC drivers are identified by text and often different ODBC drivers from Oracle have different names (e.g. "Oracle in OraHome92", "Oracle in OraClient11g_home1","Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit","Oracle in OraClient18Home1_32bit", etc.)